# File upload with Jersey, File not being decoded

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I've been trying to do file upload to a server from Javascript to a Jakarta REST service. The file is not getting decoded and I can't find what's wrong.

The upload code I'm using in javascript is basic FormData upload (vanillajs):

```
  var url=.....  
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var formData = new FormData();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (this.readyState == 4)
    {
        if (this.status == 200)
        {
            if (successCallback != null) successCallback(this.responseText);
        }
        else
        {
            if (errorCallback != null) errorCallback(this.status, this.statusText);
        }
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
  formData.append("file", file);
  xhttp.send(formData);
```

The way I'm getting the file is to use a file input, and when the user loads an image, I load a picture of it and use that (React):

```
const [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = React.useState('');

const loadImage=(e)=>{

var file=e.target.files[0];

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (e2)=>{
    setImgSrc(e2.target.result);
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

  <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={(e)=>loadImage(e)} />
```

That seems to work fine. When I look at the request headers I see:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=....
```

and the payload starts with:

```
file: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/...
```

Then the REST service I'm using to receive this is:

```
@POST
@Path("/submit")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadImage(
        @FormDataParam("file") File fileBody,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition metadata)
{
    // set up S3 bucket, all that works fine
            s3.putObject("mybucket", "pick_a_name", new FileInputStream(fileBody), null);
}
```

and that works, BUT, the file content is the literal content of the payload:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/...
```

So it's not being recognized as a base 64 encoded file content and being decoded.

I've gone through various iterations and questions, including variations that result in 400 or 415 errors, but as far as I can tell these things look like they should line up.

A few more data points:

```
  Tomcat 10
  Jakarta 3.0.0
  Jersey 3.0.3 (and jersey media multipart 3.0.3)
  Java 8
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There is no built in feature to detect base64 data and convert it. On the client side, I don't think it should automatically convert a file to base64. Are you doing it somewhere in your code? What is this `file` object on the client side? How did you create that?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I've edited to show where I get the file value (from imgSrc). Maybe that's an encoded image in memory instead of raw content?

Comment: readAsDataUrl is what converts it to base64

Comment: @PaulSamsotha thanks! you were absolutely correct. by caching the file (e.target.files[0]) instead it wasn't encoded. If you want to post this as the answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to get a "real" (what's the correct problem and solution) answer, but in the meantime I went with a hack:

```
InputStream outStream = hackBase64Decode(fileBody);
s3.putObject("mybucket", "pick_a_name", outStream, null);

    private InputStream hackBase64Decode(File fileBody) throws Exception
    {
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(fileBody);
        int ch;
        do {
            ch = fs.read();
        } while (ch != ',');
        return Base64.getDecoder().wrap(fs);
    }
```

The best that can be said for that is it works. Again, though, would prefer a real answer.